# Determining the indices of a mesh

Tags: vertices

My question is: How to show the number of indices so that I can add a fixed constraint to certain indices at physical simulation.

[image]

It works for a simple cube, but not for this mesh

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if I understood your question: Do you want to create a vertex group which can be used in constraints?

Comment: I solved it. I had to type in python console : bpy.app.debug = True. I add a picture after determining the indices.

Comment: if you solved your problem, please write it as an answer instead of editing your question. That way others will see that the question has an answer.

Comment: I added a complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

To activate the indices at blender 2.79, you type in the python console the following command

`bpy.app.debug = True`

[image]

Switch to the 3D view and press N to access the Mesh display where the indices icon is activated

[image]

Finally, you would have the indices appear on the mesh

[image]

For who is interested in for more details: these indices would be used to located where the constraint are added to the volumetric mesh in physical simulation like SOFA physics engine simulator

This how it looks like, this would facilitate adding a constraint for a volumetric mesh in a physical simulation like SOFA framework.

this how it looks like in the XML​ code:

`<FixedConstraint template="Vec3d" name="Fixed Dofs" indices="12 15 28 31" drawSize="0" />`